# How do I enable "debug" logging of the Docker daemon? (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: docker, verbose, verbosity, log-level

I want to set the verbosity level of the docker deamon in ubuntu 16.04)

Docker version = 1.12.6

The following didn't work:

- /etc/docker/daemon.json, setting"debug": true (can not find the file)
- docker -d  (error docker flag provided but not defined deamon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended way when using systemd is drop-ins. See the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/). You can create the file at `/etc/docker/daemon.json` if it does not already exist.

Add the following code snippet:

`{
    "debug": true
}`

You will need to restart the docker service at that point `sudo systemctl restart docker`

EDIT:

Because you are using an older version of Docker, you may need to do things differently.

Run `systemctl show --property=FragmentPath docker` to show the default file. This should be something like `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`

Edit this file and add `EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/docker`

Add the `-D` flag to `DOCKER_OPTS` in `/etc/default/docker` and restart the service.

Further docs for your particular version [here](https://docs.docker.com/v1.12/engine/admin/systemd/#/custom-docker-daemon-options)

Comment: Unfortunately after this my [docker ps] command stil show not debug info at all :(